# Making a bootstrap search bar with 2 inputs and one button, on a single line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a search bar using html/bootstrap/Jquery which looks similar to the search bar found here:

https://us.letgo.com/en

So far I have that design but with only one text box:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-md-6">
      <form class="" action="next_page.php" method="GET">
        <div class="form-group" id="search_wrapper">
          <input type="text" id="search_field" class="form-control" name="search_title" placeholder="Search By Name">
          <button type="submit" id="search_button" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
```

css

```
#search_field {
    background-transparent;
    height:40px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-color: #CCCCCC;
    outline: none;
} 
#search_button {

    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    font-size: 17px;
    width:120px;
    height:40px;
}
#search_wrapper{
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
}
```

When I add another input between the button and input between the input and button, the input just displays below both the button and the text box.

```
<input type="text" id="search_field" class="form-control" name="search_place" placeholder="Search By Place">
```

**EDIT 1**

I made a jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/7v6hc9sz/1/

If that doesnt just link you to it, please let me know in a comment that it doesn't work. I have never used jsfiddle before.

Comment: Show us more markup, please.  We need to see your html, including the container, and the css for that container.  Also note that you're adding a LOT of styles manually to items which could likely be styled mostly by Bootstrap.  Setting fixed widths on your input and button is probably anti-bootstrap.

Comment: @cale_b Is that good?

Comment: Yes, that's much better.  Thank you.

Comment: Check the website you used as example, they are using cols to make the forms align and by a class removing the padding so it's one next to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend leveraging the Bootstrap native styles to the maximum extent possible, as they give you a robust set of tools to build your site.

For this particular issue, you're looking for [Bootstrap's Inline Form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) styles.

Here's an example from their docs:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
</form>
```

You also are looking for [Bootstrap Input Groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) which will allow you to "pair" the button to the right of the last input.

Note the following things about that code:
1.  The form has a class of `form-inline`.  This is important, as it tells Bootstrap to line things up inline.
2. Each pair of label / inputs gets wrapped in a div with the class `form-group`.  This tells Bootstrap to display this "group" (label and input) inline.
3. Each input gets a class of `form-control`.  This tells bootstrap to style it up as an input.

Now, applying those classes to your markup, to achieve what you want, would look something like this:

```
<!-- Add the class "form-inline" -->
<h3>
Important:<br>form-inline does not appear correctly unless you make the preview pane wide!
</h3>
<form class="form-inline" action="next_page.php" method="GET">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="search_field" class="form-control" name="search_title" placeholder="Search By Name">
    <!-- close the "form-group" div and start a new div -->
  </div>
  <!-- here we use "input-group" to get the submit tight "against" the input -->
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
<button type="submit" id="search_button" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
      </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's a [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/ef9azyby/)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make an inline form - the [bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) has examples.

It looks like this:

[image]

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="inputOne">Input One</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputOne" placeholder="Input Two">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="inputTwo">Input Two</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTwo" placeholder="Input Two">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

Working [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/uFfKtAGkxN)

Here's a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/FMBJgZPbm1) with connected fields by Rachel S

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a custom CSS class to override the default margins for this form:

```
 margin-right: -10px;
```

As well as remove the rounded corners of the following input element:

```
border-top-left-radius: 0;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0
```

See **working demo** below (***need to see in in full-page***).

You'd need to add this to your nav bar, of course.

```css
.my-search {
  padding: 1px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.my-search2 input#search2 {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>my attempt</h2>
<hr/>
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group my-search">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search1" placeholder="s1">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group my-search2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search2" placeholder="s2">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```